# Tools for planning learning as a time-dependent activity?

Tags: teaching

I'm looking into planning tools for labs and lessons.  I'm wondering if there is an established tool, similar to a storyboard, that lets me plan from the perspective of skills the student will gain as they progress through an activity.  What would be really ideal is if the tool also includes gates, where students who have not gained a particular skill can't move past a certain point until they've attained mastery.

Logically, I could just draw this out, but if there is an established tool for it I'm sure someone else would make a better, more coherent thing than I could.

Edit: as an example, I'm working on a lab right now where students will learn to build circuits.  The lab might be planned like this:

Activity 1: teach students to use the voltage source
Activity 2: teach students to incorporate  the voltage source into a small circuit, teach students to build a circuit
Activity 3: students must build their own circuit without guidance.  They therefore must be able to use the voltage source and build a circuit.

In the above example, students can't progress to activity 3 without activities 1 and 2, and activities 1 and 2 would teach them the required skills.